# no carga mi modal con bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

tengo una tabla que me carga filas y cada fila me tiene que mostrar un modal con un detalle del registro de la fila, me funciona correctamente con la primera fila, pero las demas filas no me muestran el modal

codigo:

```
<tr id="pedidoDetalle">
<td><?=$r["producto"]." "?><a href="#" id="detoxDet" id_detox="<?php echo $r['id_detox'] ?>" detox="<?php echo $r['idetox']; ?>" ><?php echo $verdetalle; ?></a></td>
    <td><?=$r["total"];?></td>
    <td><?=$r["cantidad"];?></td> 
  <td><?=number_format($r["total"] * $r["cantidad"],2);?></td>
```

java script modal :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $('#detoxDet').click(function(){  
           var id = $(this).attr("detox"); 
           var id_detox = $(this).attr("id_detox");
           $.ajax({  
                url:"detalleDetox.php",  
                method:"post",  
                data:{id:id,id_detox:id_detox},  
                success:function(data){  
                    $('#detalle_detox1').html(data);  
                     $('#detalle_detox').modal("show");  
                }  
           });   
                  });  
 }); 
</script>
```

pdt: Creo que el problema es por que las filas apuntan al mismo modal, en ese caso como podria hacerlo porfavor, saludos

Comment: ¿Puedes por favor ingresar el código que utilizar para el modal? Así como explicar brevemente la estructura de tu tabla. Me parece que `id_detox` es el id principal, ¿no?

Comment: En que parte del código imprimes las modales ??

Answer (score 0):

Por convención, los id de los elementos debe ser únicos, por lo que veo en el código, y una suposición mía, la generación de la tabla estaría en un ciclo. Lo que yo haría en ese punto sería cambiar el selector de jquery por uno de clase y cambiaría el id por class en el elemento:

```
<a href="#" class="detoxDet" id_detox="<?php echo $r['id_detox'] ?>" detox="<?php echo $r['idetox']; ?>" ><?php echo $verdetalle; ?></a>
```

y en el selector:

```
//...
$('.detoxDet').click(function(){
     //tu codigo...
});
//...
```

aclaro que no he verificado todo tu código pero es lo primero que noto, y ya lo otro dependería de como tengas tu modal, ya que no lo veo en el código suministrado.

En cuanto a lo del ciclo, y lo que he mencionado de los id únicos la parte:

```
<tr id="pedidoDetalle">
```

También estaría generando ids repetidos. Si no estoy en lo correcto, sería bueno que proveas mas detalles en cuanto a tu código.